# StaticInjectorError(AppModule) Service -> InjectionToken error in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, node-modules

How to resolve below error

```
 AppComponent.html:9 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[OzaAuthService -> InjectionToken oza.config.angular]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[OzaAuthService -> InjectionToken oza.config.angular]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken oza.config.angular!
```

AuthService.ts : In AuthService calling custom "oza package".

```
import { OzaAuthService } from '@oza/oza-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  _accessToken: string;
  constructor(private ozaAuthService: OzaAuthService) {
    console.log('ozaAuthService');
    this.$getAccessToken().subscribe(token => {
      this._accessToken = token;
    });
  }

  public getAccessToken(): string {
    return this._accessToken;
  }
```

In App.module.ts imported oza package and added **OzaAuthService** in provider but still getting error.

```
import { OzaAuthService} from '@oza/oza-angular';

 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    // router
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
   **OzaAuthService**
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: any updates ? see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error, it seems that `OzaAuthService` needs an `InjectionToken` named *oza.config.angular* so as to configure the service. You need to also provide this `InjectionToken` in AppModule. Either refer to the package's documentation or try to find the exported name of the InjectionToken in the service's source code.